# Intel TBB input_node output value caching delays resource release. Workaround ideas?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, tbb, reference-counting, tbb-flow-graph

I'm new to the Intel Threading Building Blocks and playing with the flow graph component. So far, its worked mostly well. My messages between nodes are `shared_ptr` types so they are copy-constructble, lightweight, and the underlying resource is disposed of at the end of a graph cycle...

Except for messages that originate from my `input_node`. `input_node` is designed so that it holds a copy of its last output value. This means that the any resource held by the value output by an `input_node` won't be released until the `input_node` generates its next output.

This seems awkward/inconsistent with the rest of the API. Any thoughts on how to deal with it? I guess I could write my own node, but I'd rather not. Should I just use `try_put`? If so, how do I let the graph know when I'm done providing inputs, so that `wait_for_all` doesn't conclude early?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy workaround is to have the `input_node` generate a message which does not utilize `shared_ptr` types, and feeds immediately to a `function_node` whose output does utilize any `shared_ptr` types you want to propagate and have collected when the propagation is complete. It feels a little silly, but works well. There may be nodes besides `input_node` that do caching, but I'm using `function_node`, `multifunction_node`, and `indexer_node` without any evidence of the caching that `input_node` does.

As an aside, it always creeps me out a little bit when I google a problem and end up on one of my own questions on stackoverflow, and it's been long enough that I don't remember posting the question. When I don't see an answer it adds some disappointment to the emotions too. ;-)

At least on this one by the time I came back I had become used enough to TBB dataflow that an easy workaround was readily apparent.